# How to avoid escaping html characters in bottle python web framework?

Tags: python, bottle

### Question

How can I prevent escaping characters in [Bottle - Python Web Framework](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/)?

### Background

I'm making a songs lyrics webapp in Bottle (python), and I'm testing all the data is correct before inserting it to the database, so, for now, I basically have a form that has "song name", "artist", "lyrics" (in a textarea) and that's it.

When the form submits it loads a page containing the three input values mentioned above (song, artist and lyrics) and everything is working as expected but the lyrics' html is being escaped (before sending the lyrics to the template I replaced all the `\n` with `<br>`).

So I did my research and from [this tutorial from bottlepy.org](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#inline-expressions)   and found that Bottle escapes the html tags to prevent XSS attacks and you can disable this by putting a "!" before the variable name, AWESOME! I found the solution, but... when I tried to use it it threw an error:

### Error - [Screenshot of Error on computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1hTY.png)

```
Exception:

SyntaxError('invalid syntax', ('H:\\Server\\htdocs\\letras\\prueba.tpl', 4, 27, "u'<div>Letra: ', _escape( !letra['letra'] ), u'</div>'])\n"))

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "H:\Server\htdocs\letras\bottle.py", line 764, in _handle
      return route.call(**args)
    File "H:\Server\htdocs\letras\bottle.py", line 1575, in wrapper
      rv = callback(*a, **ka)
    File "index.py", line 41, in guardar_letra
      return template('prueba.tpl', letra = data)
    File "H:\Server\htdocs\letras\bottle.py", line 3117, in template
      return TEMPLATES[tplid].render(kwargs)
    File "H:\Server\htdocs\letras\bottle.py", line 3090, in render
      self.execute(stdout, kwargs)
    File "H:\Server\htdocs\letras\bottle.py", line 3078, in execute
      eval(self.co, env)
    File "H:\Server\htdocs\letras\bottle.py", line 185, in __get__
      value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)
    File "H:\Server\htdocs\letras\bottle.py", line 2977, in co
      return compile(self.code, self.filename or '<string>', 'exec')
    File "H:\Server\htdocs\letras\prueba.tpl", line 4
      u'<div>Letra: ', _escape( !letra['letra'] ), u'</div>'])
                                ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

### index.py - [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5838675)

```
from bottle import Bottle, route, run, template, static_file, get, post, request, response
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
import MySQLdb as mdb
import time
import re

@get('/enviar')
def enviar_letra():
    return template('enviar_letra.tpl')

@post('/enviar')
def guardar_letra():
    titulo = request.forms.get('titulo').capitalize() # Gets the song title from the form
    artista = request.forms.get('artista') # Gets the artist
    letra = request.forms.get('letra') # Gets the lyrics
    fecha_envio = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') # Date the lyrics were sent
    titulo = re.sub('[^\w|!|\s|\.|,]', '', titulo) # I delete every character except: words, exclamation, spaces, dots, commas
    url = titulo + "-" + artista # concatenate the song's title and the artist name to make a nice url
    url = re.sub('\W+|_', '-', url).lower() # lower all the characters from the url
    url = url.strip("-") # strips "-" at the beginning and the end
    letra = letra.replace("\n", "<br>") # replaces \n from the lyrics text area with <br>
    data = { "titulo": titulo, "artista": artista, "letra": letra, "url": url, "Fecha_envio": fecha_envio } # song dictionary
    return template('prueba.tpl', letra = data) # loads prueba.tpl template and send "data" dictionary as "letra" (letra is lyric in spanish)

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

### HTML template - [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5838911)

```
<h1>Letra de {{ letra['titulo'] }}</h1>
<h2>Por: {{ letra['artista'] }}</h2>
<div>Fecha: {{ letra['Fecha_envio'] }}</div>
<div>Letra: {{ !letra['letra'] }}</div>
```

Here's how it works/looks if I let Bottle escape my lyrics html (notice how `<br>` is being displayed as plain text):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxz7o.png

And finally, this is how ITS SUPPOSED to look

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b58J.png

Comment: Please post your code **here**, and not on an external site. We want questions to be useful to everyone, now and in the future.

Comment: Your error messages are text, please copy and paste those here too.

Comment: Generally speaking, you do the newline-to-break conversion in the template; as late as possible.

Comment: I tried, but only the first line of my whole code was being detected as code, so I had to indent every single line of my code to make it show properly :/ that's why I decided to use an external site for my code.

Comment: We can help you format it; see [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) for more detailed help. The post editor has a special button for indenting your code, select the text and click on the `{}` icon.

Comment: Hi, I just edited the post, I was able to fix the code blocks issue. Regarding my main issue, I did what you suggested, I did the newline-to-break conversion in the template but the result was the same. 
`<h1>Letra de {{ letra['titulo'] }}</h1>
<h2>Por: {{ letra['artista'] }}</h2>
<div>Fecha: {{ letra['Fecha_envio'] }}</div>
<div>Letra: {{ letra['letra'].replace("\n", "<br>") }}</div>`

Comment: Indeed; it appears bottle's templates doesn't have a construct for doing that for you. It's easier to prevent XSS when you escape the text *first*, *then* replace newlines to breaks. Your `letra['letra']` text is now open to XSS attacks because you have to interpret the whole text as HTML.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to place the exclamation mark *right after* the opening `{{` for bottle to recognize it:

```
<div>Letra: {{! letra['letra'] }}</div>
```

Preferably, you want to omit the spaces there altogether, to be on the safe side:

```
<div>Letra: {{!letra['letra']}}</div>
```

Comment: Wow, you're fast. I had reached that conclusion myself, but I JUST finished poring through the bottle.py code to prove it.

Comment: Wow I can't believe it was this easy! Sometime we spend a lot of time over-thinking problems and they end up being something really stupid :P, this was the issue, I removed all the spaces and it now works as expected, thank you for saving me more hours of thinking, I can happily go to sleep now, it's almost 5am here. Thanks again!!!

Btw, I now I'm open to XSS attacks now, but I'm going to make a custom escape function to allow only alphanumerics, !,. and <br> tags, the rest is going to be deleted!